# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nib, naming, uncaught-exception

Ive recently renamed all of my xcode file names and the project name as well, it used to be called HelloThere and I have changed it to BoatTracker and have renamed .h, .m and xib files correspondently. I used the refractor-rename feature in xcode to do this. 
I am now getting errors which i believe are name related. 
I Have already tried commenting out release statements and resetting the simulator and my my Iphone. 
The errors I receive are.

Simulator: 
All Output

```
2013-04-15 16:34:29.672 BoatTracker[22010:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Mitch/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/02CD3764-5212-42F8-A456-408E487C628D/BoatTracker.app> (loaded)' with name 'HelloThereViewController''
```

*** First throw call stack:

```
(0x18a9012 0x1269e7e 0x18a8deb 0x70bef9 0x5d07e7 0x5d0dc8 0x5d0ff8 0x5d1232 0x1ddf 0x4ed1af 0x4ed7a1 0x4ee94b 0x4ffcb5 0x500beb 0x4f2698 0x1ce9df9 0x1ce9ad0 0x181ebf5 0x181e962 0x184fbb6 0x184ef44 0x184ee1b 0x4ee17a 0x4efffc 0x1d5d 0x1c95)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

See Simulator picture:
[image]

Iphone:

```
2013-04-15 16:37:02.925 BoatTracker[153:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/C2023052-697F-40BD-A3FA-A0D5772C6DC0/BoatTracker.app> (loaded)' with name 'HelloThereViewController''
```

*** First throw call stack:

```
(0x345c32a3 0x3c26897f 0x345c31c5 0x36568571 0x36567b9b 0x3646003d 0x363ea46d 0x31459 0x3642bb1d 0x3642b6a3 0x3642384b 0x363cbc39 0x363cb6cd 0x363cb11b 0x380ce5a3 0x34598683 0x34597ee9 0x34596cb7 0x34509ebd 0x34509d49 0x36422485 0x3641f301 0x313ad 0x3c69fb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

See Iphone picture:
[image]

If you need any code samples to help find the problem please ask.

Comment: Reset your iphone simulator, then clean and build.

Comment: Some how it still errors any other suggestions?

Comment: Check your XIB directory by clicking on it and put it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your XIB (or Storyboard) still has a reference to `HelloThereViewController`. Probably safest to update it in Xcode but you might also be able to do a search-and-replace by opening the XIB file in a text editor.

Comment: Thanks had a look though and found HelloThereViewController reference.

Comment: I fixed the previous error by adjusting the xib settings in main.h how would I go about changing the settings on user created view controllers as im getting the same error when trying to access them.

Comment: Fixed - adjusting initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" with initWithNibName:@"AlarmViewController"